# How to reset the input stream in python?

Tags: python, input, command-prompt

i am writing a prompt argument in Python 2.7 in order to import my data file with a Command-line interface.

```
REFERENCE = raw_input("Reference (*.shp):")
SEGMENTED = raw_input("Segmented (*.shp):")
METHOD = raw_input("Method (ke, pu, clinton):")
if METHOD != "ke" and METHOD != "pu" and METHOD != "clinton":
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid method" % METHOD)
if METHOD == "ke" or METHOD == "clinton":
    THRESHOLD = input("Threshold (0.0 - 1.0):")
    if not check_threshold(THRESHOLD):
        raise AccuracyException("Threshold of %s is not valid" % THRESHOLD)
else:
    THRESHOLD = None
SEP = raw_input("Sep:")
if SEP != "space" and SEP != "tab" and SEP != "comma" and SEP != "colon" and SEP != "semicolon" and SEP != "hyphen" and SEP != "dot":
    raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % SEP)
HEADER = raw_input("Header (True/False):")
if HEADER.strip() != "True" and HEADER.strip() != "False":
    raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % HEADER)
# output 
OUTPUT = raw_input("Output (*.txt):")
```

after load i wish to reset from the start in order to import new data without reload the *.py file, because my goal is convert the *.py in an *.exe using py2exe

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: put everything in a `while` loop and only exit on user's input (one additional input like `raw_input("Wanna quit?")`?

Comment: @Robᵩ : How to reset the input stream in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as DJV suggested, I think it is as simple as wrapping your script in a while loop to continue at the top of the while block after the user goes through all the options

```
while True:
  REFERENCE = raw_input("Reference (*.shp):")
  SEGMENTED = raw_input("Segmented (*.shp):")
  METHOD = raw_input("Method (ke, pu, clinton):")
  if METHOD != "ke" and METHOD != "pu" and METHOD != "clinton":
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid method" % METHOD)
  if METHOD == "ke" or METHOD == "clinton":
    THRESHOLD = input("Threshold (0.0 - 1.0):")
    if not check_threshold(THRESHOLD):
        raise AccuracyException("Threshold of %s is not valid" % THRESHOLD)
  else:
    THRESHOLD = None
  SEP = raw_input("Sep:")
  if SEP != "space" and SEP != "tab" and SEP != "comma" and SEP != "colon" and SEP != "semicolon" and SEP != "hyphen" and SEP != "dot":
    raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % SEP)
  HEADER = raw_input("Header (True/False):")
  if HEADER.strip() != "True" and HEADER.strip() != "False":
    raise ValueError("%s is not valid" % HEADER)
  # output 
  OUTPUT = raw_input("Output (*.txt):")
```